# Using ArcGIS in Android Studio?

Tags: arcgis-android, arcgis-runtime, intellij-idea

I want to using ArcGIS in Android Studio. I followed this [Developing with the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android and Intellij IDEA](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/10/26/developing-with-the-arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-android-and-intellij-idea/) blog.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
    compile files('libs/ArcGIS_Android.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.9.5.jar')


}
```

And I added as a jar file to libs folder :
ArcGIS_Android
jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.5.jar
jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.9.5.jar

And I am getting this errors:
Gradle: package com.esri.android.map does not exist
Gradle: package com.esri.android.map.ags does not exist
Gradle: cannot find symbol class MapView
Gradle: cannot find symbol class ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer

Arcgis jar is appear external libraries. And I am getting errors at run time not compile.

Comment: What version of the Android SDK are you using?  We have an updated blog post here > http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/10/31/arcgis-android-development-with-intellij-idea/ for working with 10.2.  Also, what version of Android Studio are you working with?  Android Studio is a moving target so help will depend on what version you are currently using.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you native libs?  To compile the *.jar files from your libs folder add the following to your dependencies:

`// local binary dependency
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

The best way to work with the ArcGIS Android SDK is to update to v10.2.3 and use our Android SDK EAP library module from [Github](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-android-api-lib-module) in your project.  We have an [EAP sample repo](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-android-sdk-gradle-samples) as well which show integrating the library module.